# Regular expression with sed

Tags: linux, sed

```
./Queen/(1986)/Innuendo/01.One vision.mp3
./Queen/(1986)/Innuendo/02.One vision.mp3
./Queen/(1986)/Innuendo/03.One vision.mp3
```

I want to display above line as:

```
01.One vision.mp3
02.One vision.mp3
03.One vision.mp3
```

I tried with:

```
  sed -i 's/^[^.$/]/ /g/
```

Comment: `sed -i 's|/|\n/; /\n/D'` will progressively chop off chunks before `/` till the time there's no `/` left and what remains is the basename of the `.mp3s`

Comment: Sed -i 's|.*/||' abc.txt it works thanks to everyone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use `basename` for this? For example:

```
for file in *mp3; do basename "$file"; done
```

Comment: It appears that OP wants to modify a file in place (see the `-i` flag in their example).

Answer (score 11):

Your main problem is that you're trying to use `/` as a separator, when `/` also is a character you'll be parsing.

You'll need to use a different separator, such as a pipe. Match everything and a `/`, then use `\(` and `\)` (capture groups) delimiting the part you want to extract, and use `\1`, rendering that group:

```
echo "yourstring" | sed 's|.*/\([^/]*\)$|\1|'
```

You may have it working without capture groups: just dropping everything until the last `/`:

```
echo "yourstring" | sed 's|.*/||'
```

Comment: You can also backslash escape the slash in the regex and still use slashes for separators,       ie. `sed 's/.*\///'`, but it can be a pain in the ass to read.